# Q&A - Angular CLI: Using CSS preprocessors globally

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

How can I use preprocessors in my ng2 app? I'm using angular-cli and [the original docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration) are not clear enough for me. Besides, I want to use the styles globally, not only component-wide.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install your CSS compiler: [Search npm for your preffered](https://www.npmjs.com/) extension language.

   - Tested and recommended for SASS: `npm install node-sass --save-dev`
2. Add your "to be processed" file to `src/assets/css` (with the normal file extension, e.g. `.sass`)
3. Add the style ref to the `index.html` file:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/whatever.css">` - note the `.css` file extension.
4. Update your build file (`angular-cli-build.js`) with the folder of your "to be processed" files. This object HAS to be placed before the `vendorNpmFiles`-array.:

   `sassCompiler: { //(lessCompiler or stylusCompiler)
     includePaths: [
       'app/assets/css' //Only the folder, not your file!
     ]
   }`

Bonus answer: Why don't I use direct paths to files instead of the includePath? Because you may want to use variable files, so it could get really messy with absolute paths!

Answer (score 0):

The Angular CLI has built in support for Sass/SCSS, Less, and Stylus. [See here.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration)

As of the Webpack update to the CLI, there are no extra steps other than renaming your stylesheets with the appropriate extension.

For the previous System.js/Broccoli versions, it was also necessary to install the preprocessor packages to your app, like so: `npm install node-sass --save-dev`.

It will automatically process the stylesheets within and under the `src` folder.